# Downloading OpenStreetMap and Imagery to ArcGIS Collector for Offline Use?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, imagery, arcgis-collector, vector-tile-package

I am traveling to Costa Rica and would like to use Collector with my cell phone to record some information in a feature class.  I would like to find some 1m or better imagery to put in a web map that could be synced for offline use.

Does anyone have suggestions for Costa Rica imagery that is publicly available?

Also, is it possible to publish OpenStreetMap as a vector tile package for the same offline use?

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @RussRoberts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246435/download-openstreetmap-and-imagery-to-arcgis-collector-for-offline-use#comment386700_246435):

> The current release of Collector does not support vector tile
>   packages. If you have vector data you can create just a tile package
>   and side load that into Collector or Publish it as a tile layer and
>   have it support Export Tiles(same for imagery). Here are the esri
>   provided basemaps
>   http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?id=3a890be7a4b046c7840dc4a0446c5b31&start=1&view=list&sortOrder=asc&sortField=title#content

and in a [second comment by the same user](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246435/download-openstreetmap-and-imagery-to-arcgis-collector-for-offline-use#comment387029_246435):

> When you download in collector you can specify an extent before
>   downloading but there is a tile export limit. You might want to chunk
>   it up into different zones and have collector download a general
>   "master zone" and the basemap switcher will show all offline basemaps
>   that are within your downloaded extent so you can hit different lower
>   levels.